# How to structure API client code so it doesn't raise MyPy union-attr error

Tags: python, mypy

I'm developing a Python API client. I use type annotations I have working code that does what I want it to do but MYPY is flagging the following errors:

```
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:8: error: Item "ErrorResponse" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:8: error: Item "None" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:9: error: Item "ErrorResponse" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:9: error: Item "None" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:11: error: Item "ErrorResponse" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
eth-2-key-manager-api-client/examples/list_remote_keys.py:11: error: Item "None" of "ListRemoteKeysResponse | ErrorResponse | None" has no attribute "data"  [union-attr]
```

MyPy docs -> https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list.html#check-that-attribute-exists-in-each-union-item-union-attr

I understand why it is flagging it - it is clear from the error. eth_2_key_manager.list_remote_keys.sync_detailed() will return ListRemoteKeysResponse which has data attribute if the request is successful and ErrorResponse which does not have data attribute if the request is not successful.

However I ensure that the response type is ListRemoteKeysResponse type by making sure that the status_code is 200 (if response.status_code == 200:) which means that my code will never try to access .data attribute on ErrorResponse type.

This the code that MYPY is flagging:

```
eth_2_key_manager = eth_2_key_manager_api_client.Eth2KeyManager()
response = eth_2_key_manager.list_remote_keys.sync_detailed()

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Validator: {eth_2_key_manager.client.base_url}")
    print(f"Number of remote keys: {len(response.parsed.data)}")
    if response.parsed.data:
        print("List of keys:")
        for key in response.parsed.data:
            print(f"    {key.pubkey}")
else:
    print(f"List remote keys failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
```

This the list_remote_keys.sync_detailed() code:

```
def sync_detailed(
self,
) -> Response[Union[ListRemoteKeysResponse, ErrorResponse]]:
"""List Remote Keys (synchronous).

List all remote validating pubkeys known to this validator client binary

Raises:
    errors.UnexpectedStatus: If the server returns an undocumented status code and Client.raise_on_unexpected_status is True.
    httpx.TimeoutException: If the request takes longer than Client.timeout.

Returns:
    Response object containing the response from the server, response headers, status code and ListRemoteKeysResponse object if the request succeeds, otherwise an ErrorResponse object.
"""

kwargs = _get_kwargs(client=self.client, endpoint=self.ENDPOINT, method=self.METHOD)

response = httpx.request(
    verify=self.client.verify_ssl,
    **kwargs,
)

return _build_response(client=self.client, response=response, cls=ListRemoteKeysResponse)
```

Models for the two possible responses (abbreviated):

```
@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class ListRemoteKeysResponse:
    """
    Attributes:
        data (List['ListRemoteKeysResponseDataItem']):
    """

    data: List["ListRemoteKeysResponseDataItem"]
    additional_properties: Dict[str, Any] = attr.ib(init=False, factory=dict)
    


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class ErrorResponse:
    """
    Attributes:
        message (str): Detailed error message Example: description of the error that occurred.
    """

    message: str
    additional_properties: Dict[str, Any] = attr.ib(init=False, factory=dict)
```

Adding

```
assert isinstance(response.parsed, eth_2_key_manager_api_client.models.list_remote_keys_response.ListRemoteKeysResponse)
```

satisfies MyPy.

My questions are:

1. Is this the correct way to structure the API code?
2. What is the better / correct way to handle it so that users of the API client that use static type checking won't have to deal with this error?